# App is crashing on getting locale with [NSLocale currentLocale] code in Objective-C

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, localization, ios15

Why app crashes on getting current locale. It is not for every device. I'm getting this crash on a specific iPhone 13 Pro not all iPhone 13 Pro physical devices.Please help me if possible solution is available for it. My App is not supporting Simulators at all.

---

```
Crashlytics StackTrace
```

---

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE 0x000000016bcfffb0
CoreFoundation
_CFLocaleCopyCurrentGuts + 4
SKCountryPicker.m - Line 74
-[SKCountryPicker defaultCountryCode] + 74  
SKCountryPicker.m - Line 81
-[SKCountryPicker getCountryDetailBasedOnSIMAndIOSSettings] + 81
SKCountryPicker.m - Line 94
-[SKCountryPicker getCountryDetailForCountryCode:] + 94  
SKCountryPicker.m - Line 81
-[SKCountryPicker getCountryDetailBasedOnSIMAndIOSSettings] + 81
SKCountryPicker.m - Line 94
-[SKCountryPicker getCountryDetailForCountryCode:] + 94
SKCountryPicker.m - Line 87
-[SKCountryPicker getCountryDetailBasedOnSIMAndIOSSettingsForCountryList:] + 87
SKCountryPicker.m - Line 65
__49-[SKCountryPicker getCountryListSuccess:failure:]_block_invoke_2 + 65
Foundation
__NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 4330003460
Foundation
-[NSBlockOperation main] + 4330004024
Foundation
__NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ + 4330003460
Foundation
-[NSOperation start] + 4330004024
Foundation
__NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 4330003460
Foundation
__NSOQSchedule_f + 4330004024
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 4330003460
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_client_callout + 4330004024
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_main_queue_drain + 4330003460
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 4330004024
CoreFoundation
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 4330003460
```

---

```
StackTrace ProgramCode Line 74 and 81 :
```

---

```
-(NSString*)defaultCountryCode {
    NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    NSString *countryCode = [currentLocale objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
    return countryCode;
}

-(SKCountry*)getCountryDetailBasedOnSIMAndIOSSettings {
    SKCountry *selectedCountryData = [self getCountryDetailForCountryCode: [self defaultCountryCode]];
    return selectedCountryData;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please share the crash stack and message. I suppose that you talk about crashes that are happening on physical devices. Did you check if the app crashes in a simulator of devices with which you have problems?

Comment: Thanks Blazej,
Actually I'm getting it on production build. So I've crashlytics stacktrace

Comment: Thank @dbc,
I've update my question as text instead of images.